# Why does the reading Thread not "run out"?

Tags: java, multithreading, stream

I am trying to understand some things about threads in java, which I am very unfamiliar with. Unfortunately my example is too big for running code, but I'll try to specify my problem as well as possible.

One of two similar code segments (taken from a little example which features a simple ChatClient/Server class), which are the center of my question:

```
public void run(){
    String message;
        try{
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){...}
}
```

(Taken from an inner class of the Server class.)

The server is waiting in a `while(true)` loop for clients via its serversockets `accept()` method and whenever a client connects, a new `Thread` is started with the above run method as "entry point".

What I don't understand is why this works. My understanding until now was that `Thread` which is supposed to constantly listen to something has to contain a `while(true)` construct because otherwise it would just finish it's run method and it would be finished with no return ("dead" call stack).

So for my example when reader gave us all lines he had to give in the beginning, I supposed it would leave the `run()`-method and nothing would happen when the specific client would send a new message but it seems it stays listening for client input. How does that work?

(I probably should say that "reader" is a `BufferedReader` within the inner class which is instantiated once for every connected client.)

I hope that was sufficiently explained. If more Information is needed I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readLine()` *blocks* while there is no data. It only returns null at end of stream, which in the case of a socket means that the peer has disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that solves this for me! I wasn't aware of this behaviour; i thought it would be the same as with reading from a text-file (which i tested), which is why i was expecting to just get a null.

Comment: You get a null at end of stream. It isn't different. Maybe you thought you would get a null when the sender stopped sending, and a non-null afterwards when he sent again?

Comment: Yes that's more or less it; especially the first point is what i thought; at least when we define "stopped sending" as "no more lines which can be read from the client". When you say "peer has disconnected" do you mean that the server has a null-reference in the client-socket?

Answer (score 1):

If the client does not send anything, the server socket does not have anything to read. When the client writes to the socket and the contents are sent the reader can read the contents